# open view as modal in different view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, controller, bootstrap-modal

Here is the scenario. I have two views. "contact.cshtml" and "xyz.cshtml" with two different controllers.

On contact.cshtml page I have text fields and a button. once User completes the text fields, on "next" button click, it should go to a controller action.(this I achieved using jquery ajax post).
the second controller action will return a partial view(xyz.cshtml). But I need it as modal popup/window in the contact.cshtml without page reload.

I want xyz.cshtml as a modal on contact.cshtml.

Any answer will be appreciated and upvoted.

contact.cshtml

```
<button type="button" onclick="next()" class="btn>next</button>`

function next(){
  $.post('secondcontroller/abcaction', {})
    .done(function() {})
    .fail(function(){})
}
```

second controller

```
public ActionResult abcaction()   
{
  return View("xyz.cshtml");
}
```

xyz.cshtml second controller abcaction view

```
<div class="content">I'm partial view</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the bootstrap modal as referenced [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals), you mave have an empty div for modal data. Then, you can pass the response received from AJAX inside that modal and trigger it to show.

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          //placeholder for my modal data
    </div>
```

and your ajax function

```js
function next(){
  $.post('secondcontroller/abcaction', function(response){
      $("#myModal").html(response);
  })
    .done(function() {$("#myModal").modal("show");})
    .fail(function(){})
}
```

Comment: `abcaction` should return a `PartialView`, eh? Otherwise layout(s) will be applied, which is rarely the intention.